# NTFS mount under Linux: Slow transfer speeds

Tags: hard-disk, samba, xfs, file-transfer

I am migrating my home server from Windows to Ubuntu server 22.04. Some of the data I am migrating is on an NTFS drive and I want to transfer this data to a new (second) drive which is using XFS. However I am encountering very low transfer speeds ranging from 40 MB/s to 1 MB/s. Hdparm gives read speeds of around 230 MB/s unbuffered for the drives in question.

The drives are connected via motherboard SATA but I get similar results via an HBA (LSI 9211-8i IT mode) well. The drives are Seagate iron wolf 10Tb and 8Tb spinning disks. The motherboard is a gigabyte X399 aorus xtreme running an AMD threadripper 1920x. The files are mixed: video files (average 4GB) photos (8-20MB) and lots of smaller files >10 Mb.

While the drives were both connected in the Ubuntu server (via sata) I was getting transfer speeds of 1-3 MB/s using cp and around 7-8 MB/s using rsync.
Not sure if it makes any difference but I formatted the XFS drives with the reverse mapping b-tree option (-m rmapbt=1).

The fstab entry for the xfs drive has the following options:
*auto,rw,sync,noexec,nodev,nosuid,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=sdisk2*

When the ntfs drive was mounted in the Linux server it had the following fstab mount options: *auto ro 0 0*

From my basic google-fu I have managed to test:

1. checking write-cache - confirmed enabled on the drives in question.
2. potential bottleneck with NTFS drivers under Linux - see below.
3. moving sata ports - this made no difference.

To test point 2 I connected the NTFS drive to a wired network windows box and then made the XFS drive available via samba - this increased the transfer speed to around 30-40MB/s - using explorer. So maybe part of the issue was the Linux NTFS driver. This is the best result thus far, but I assume this is well below what should be expected, at least based on my previous windows-only transfer experience.

I not sure what else to check. I am relatively new to Linux (learning a lot over the past two weeks) and would be grateful for any assistance.

Thanks,

FM

Comment: Linux perfectly supports NTFS using ntfs-3g or native ntfs3 driver. I'm not sure why you need to move data around at all. From your description it's impossible to say whether you're moving files within the same drive or between drivers. If it's the former, the copy speed will naturally be a lot lower.

Comment: Can confirm that ntfs-3g is very slow, so slow it's tedious for backup purposes, i.e. for a one-way copy-off-ntfs-to-xfs. That's mostly the result of it being an old userland driver, and maybe also code efficiency issues. The workaround I went with was a minimal Windows VM on the same computer, attaching the NTFS disk to that VM, and as you said, copying via shared folder (in my case, virtiofs, but the cost of samba/CIFS should be tolerable)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov between two separate drives - will amend my post to clarify. The reason is that I intend to use mergerfs and pool a number of xfs drives. I have no ongoing need for NTFS on the server and wish to take advantage of native linux filesystems.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you. That is an interesting way I had not considered. Will try this and see if it works any better.

Comment: There's just one Linux fs that I fully trust and that's ext4. With everything else I've seen people lose a ton of data. NTFS-3G is only slow when writing/creating a huge number of small files while its speed is near native when transferring large files, like the OP has. I've no idea where the bottleneck is. Please try running a recent enough version of `iotop` and check your disks IO load in %. And run top/htop as well. If you notice that the ntfs-3g process eats 100% of your CPU, then it makes a lot of sense to mount your NTFS partitions using native `ntfs3`.

Comment: no, it's not acceptably fast, @ArtemS.Tashkinov. I have the experience it isn't. That's also not surprising – again, it's a userland file system driver, doesn't support any of the modern context-switch avoidance techniques, and that means copying a large file means a lot of read()/write() calls which, every single one, go from the file-reading userland program (`cp`) to kernel to userland filesystem to kernel reading the underlying block device to userlandfilesystem to kernel and finally back to the reading program (`cp`); and that's the best case. It's simply slow :(

Comment: And it simply runs at native speeds here. I have literally no difference for my HDD between Windows 10 and ntfs-3g. None. The transfer speed could be affected if the utility to transfer file uses a small buffer (<128KB), everything from 128KB and above will be fast. E.g check this: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3624 https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/commit/7b928e6b9400360cb9cd79edd8932dc60620898c

Comment: I can imagine certain utilities using a copy buffer of just 4KB which will decimate read/write speeds for NTFS-3G. Don't use those. Again, a 128KB read/write buffer is excellent (more than 128KB is even better).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov it's really nice that it works for you. OP clearly states they use cp or rsync. These aren't exotic tools. Is it possible that the actual contents file system you're reading are simply ... simpler than those that OP deals with?

Comment: If the OP uses something like Debian 9, I can imagine all sorts of issues. Again, I've offered to use newer or better utilities as well as the native ntfs3 driver which mustn't have this issue. Using a VM with Windows sounds like a total overkill and a complete waste of time.

Comment: I'd even try something like `tar c here/is/the/stuff | tar -C /where/it/should/go -x` - this could work a whole lot faster.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov hm, I see it solved my issue, so it's hardly a waste of time! Can you try to be a bit nicer to me?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try copying files this way?

```bash
tar c source/directory | pv -petrab | tar -C /destination/directory -x
```

(with the hint by @MarcusMüller)

Comment: I like this approach by the way (+1 from me!), and I think you can, since tar really doesn't care about any behaviour of the output stream, insert `| pv ` between, i.e. `tar c source/directory | pv --average-rate | tar -C /destination/directory -x`, and get live statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your answers. Both have been very useful and I am very pleased to say worked a treat - back up to ~230Mb/s. For good measure I reformatted the target drive to ext4 and tried both options and both gave very comparable results. I've opted for the tar command, mostly because I am increasingly becoming more comfortable operating via cli.

Just so that I understood the tar command you've kindly provided, the start (tar -c) creates an archive and compresses the source folder then pipes this in some streaming fashion to be decompressed (tar -C -x) at the target folder, with the intermediate PV command providing progress, stats etc. Is this correct?

Apologies for putting this in the answer section. I originally posted as an unregistered user and the password/registration email process seems to have created a new user with the same name! And this is the only place I can post this. In any case you have my thanks.